# HTML Form That Doesn't Actually Submit Anything To The Server (Client-Side Processing in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I have an HTML form with inputs that will only do client-side processing in JavaScript and jQuery, but won't actually submit anything to the server. What is the proper way of laying out out such a form in HTML and writing JavaScript that will process a form when the form's inputs change (both on an explicit submit event (i.e. clicking 'Submit' or Enter), or on an implicit change event (un-focusing from an input, or even on every keystroke/click of an input's text))?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really never submit the form to somewhere, you can avoiding use a form tag at all. And just use input boxes and buttons. Then if the user clicks the button, either your click handler runs, or nothing happens at all.

As for catching the explicit events, button click, unfocus (blur) I would suggest jQuery as it makes it really easy to attach handlers to those events in a cross-browser way.

- http://api.jquery.com/click/
- http://api.jquery.com/blur/
- http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Interesting; for some reason I thought a `<form>` tag was a required parent element of `<input>`. So just use "formless" input elements and bind event-handlers to 'em with jQuery?

Comment: I've done that exact thing before, and it has worked out just fine :) I'm not sure if its 100% "in-spec" according to whatever doctype you might be using, but I didn't encounter any issues that I recall.

Comment: @Paul: see my answer for an alternative view of this

Comment: You miss out on Enter key handling if you don't use the <form> element. This is a pet peeve of mine when I visit sites that don't submit when I press Enter.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly prevent the default form action by returning false in the onsubmit or by using event.preventDefault() in the event handler.

Inline:

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return false" action="pleaseturnonjavascript.html">
```

better:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit=function() {
    // do something with the form field
    return false; // old way
  }
}
```

using preventDefault:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit=function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // first statement
    // do something with the form field
  }
}
```

or jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myform").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // first statement
    // do something with the form field
  });
});
```

then decide if you want to use onkeyup (I use that in number fields) or onblur (used when the complete value is important)

This can be done using plain old JavaScript or jQuery, but we need more information to help you further

I prefer using the form tag and pass the form object instead of just have input fields that have to be accessed per field instead of using the form elements array - I feel unhappy not wrapping inputs in a form tag. It might not even validate and the added benefit is that enter will trigger the submit event without other measures.

Comment: Inputs are ***not*** required to be nested in forms. "The elements used to create controls generally appear inside a FORM element, but may also appear outside of a FORM element declaration when they are used to build user interfaces." (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-controls) However, a benefit of using a FORM element would be the LEGEND and FIELDSET elements, which add structure to forms.

Comment: FORM elements are ***required*** to have an "action" attribute. "This attribute specifies a form processing agent. User agent behavior for a value other than an HTTP URI is undefined." What should it be in this case? Empty? A slash?

Comment: perhaps a page that explains your form only works if javascript is turned on?

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion because it allows the user to "submit" the form (register a click event on the submit button) by pressing enter, without the form tag, the user must click submit because pressing enter will not work.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a form tag.  You can use the attach functions to each element, like so:

```
 $("#input-element-id").change(function(){
  //your code here
  });
```

or you can wrap a containing DIV (or other element) around them all, and do this:

```
$("#containing-div-id").change(function() {
//your code here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

just go through some examples on w3school site http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp

you can get an idea on how to write onclick ,onmouseover events

Comment: That is not the favourite site to suggest since it is full of errors and has not been updated for a long time according to best practises

Comment: Lol I learned basics from that site. So I thought It would be helpful. i'll take your point from next time. Thanks for warning me.

Comment: I know. A lot of people have. Which is why many of them come here to be thoroughly educated in no uncertain terms ;))) Just try posting a `setTimeout("functionName()",1000)` and see the downvoting ;)